# change session id after logout in php

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I want to restore session id after the users logout to the session id they have before login. I store the session id at the moment users login but I don't know have to change it in the cookie stored on the users browsers.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//before loggin 
        $_SESSION['old_session'] = $_SESSION;
        //During logout
        $old_session  = $_SESSION['old_session'];
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION = $old_session;
```